# I just can't delete one of my user addresses in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm having some problems when I'm going to delete one of my user's addresses. I want to let you know that the user has a relation One To Many with the table of Addresses.

Here, I'm just trying to delete the Address through his 'id', but it doesn't work.

**UserController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use App\Address;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function deleteAddress(User $user, Address $address) {   
    $address->user->is($user); 

    $address->destroy();

    return redirect()->back();
  }
}
```

**{Routes} Web.php**

```
<?php


 Route::get('/', [
'uses' => 'ProductController@getIndex',
'as' => 'welcome.index'
 ]);

 Route::get('/products/{product}', [ 
'uses' => 'ProductController@showOne',
'as' => 'welcome.show'
 ]);


 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
 Route::get('/user/profile', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@userProfile',
    'as' => 'user.profile'
 ]);

Route::get('/user/profile/account', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@userAccount',
    'as' => 'user.account'
]);

Route::patch('/user/profile/account/{user}/name-update',  [
    'uses' => 'UserController@nameUpdate',
    'as' => 'user.nameUpdate'
]);

Route::patch('/user/profile/account/{user}/email-update',  [
    'uses' => 'UserController@emailUpdate',
    'as' => 'user.emailUpdate'
]);

Route::patch('/user/profile/account/{user}/password-update',  [
    'uses' => 'UserController@passwordUpdate',
    'as' => 'user.passwordUpdate'
]);

Route::get('/user/profile/address', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getAddress',
    'as' => 'user.address'
]);

Route::post('/user/profile/address/{user}/create', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@newAddress',
    'as' => 'user.newAddress'
]);

Route::post('/user/profile/address/{address}/delete', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@deleteAddress',
    'as' => 'user.deleteAddress',
]);

Route::get('/logout', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout',
    'as' => 'logout'
]);
}); 

Auth::routes();
```

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title')
Account
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    @include('partials.list-group')
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h3 class="pt-3">Manage your address</h3>
    <p>In order to create a quicker and simpler way of shopping, you can create and save your addresses. Enter and save yours.</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="full-name pt-3 col-md-12">
        @foreach(Auth::user()->addresses->chunk(3) as $addresses)
        <div class="row">
        @foreach($addresses as $address)
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div class="card-title">
                                <div class="delete-button">
                                    <form method="post" action="{{ Route('user.deleteAddress', $address) }}">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        {{ method_field('delete') }}
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="address-user pb-2">
                                    <h6>{{ $address->first_name }} {{ $address->last_name }}</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="address-info">
                                    <p>{{ $address->street_address }}, {{ $address->street_address2 }}, {{ $address->city }}, {{ $address->country }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="phone type-address">
                                    <p>Phone: {{ $address->phone_number }}</p>
                                    <p>Alt phone: {{ $address->phone_number2 }}</p>
                                    <p>Type: {{ $address->address_type }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus mr-2"></i> Add a new address 
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                    <hr>
                    <div class="card">
                        <form class="card-body" method="post" action="{{ route('user.newAddress', $user) }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('First name') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Last name') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="streetAddress" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('First address') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="streetAddress" type="text" class="form-control" name="street_address" placeholder="Street 123" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="streetAddress2" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Other address') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="streetAddress2" type="text" class="form-control" name="street_address2" placeholder="Apartment/Suite 00" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="country" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Country') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <select style="height:38px" name="country" id="country" class="col-md-12 col-form-label text-md-left">
                                            <option value="COL">Colombia</option>
                                            <option value="USA">United States</option>
                                            <option value="MEX">Mexico</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="stateProvince" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('State/Province') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="stateProvince" type="text" class="form-control" name="state_province" placeholder="California" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="city" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('City') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="San Francisco" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="phoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Phone number') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="phoneNumber" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" placeholder="000-000-0000" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="phoneNumber2" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Alternate phone') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="phoneNumber2" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number2" placeholder="000-000-0000" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="addressType" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Address type') }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <select style="height:38px" name="address_type" id="addressType" class="col-md-12 col-form-label text-md-left">
                                            <option value="Home/House">House/Home</option>
                                            <option value="Business/Office">Office/Business<option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md">
                                        <a class="text-dark mr-2" style="cursor:pointer"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><u>Cancel</u></a>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>   
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Every kind of help is welcomed.

**[Throwing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfwm0.png)**

Comment: Is there any error message it throws? Best way to debug is to check what each and every statement returns.

Comment: I updated my question. Look at the picture

Comment: Route goes to `AddressController` since you have written `AddressController@deleteAddress`, but your actual `deleteAddress` method is in `UserController`

Comment: You have all the reason. I change it. Throwing the same error again.

Comment: ok, you will have to provide us more information about what is `$address` in the blade file. Is it an object or just a string? Better post your complete blade file and let us know what each `relevant` PHP variable in it means.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please, check it.

Comment: So, `$address` is an object. You can't pass it as is to the route in your blade file, it needs to have a value. For example, `<form method="post" action="{{ Route('user.deleteAddress', $address->id) }}">`. 

Also, I saw the image you have attached. You can't access the URL directly through your browser. This is because, route is a `POST` request and you are trying to access the page on your browser which is a `GET` request. Hence, it throws the error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. If you still want to access it, download `POSTMAN(chrome extension)`  and you could proceed with it.

Comment: I'm not trying to access that page. Just when I click on the button for delete the address, it throws me that error. So, what can I do for avoiding the error? Because I add it $address->id to the form, but when I click on the button of delete, it throws me the same error. Why am I thinking that the problem is in the controller?

Comment: Then it's fine. I can still see in your routes that you have `AddressController@deleteAddress` instead of `UserController@deleteAddress`. Also, if you want to delete the address  just by it's `id`, then why use POST? You can make it work on `GET` as well.

Comment: But a lot of people don't recommend it for doing it. Which is the easiest and best way to delete it?

Comment: Ok, I am trying to devise a solution. Can you let me know what this helper function `{{ method_field('delete') }}` actually gives you in HTML?

Comment: Excuse me, how can I do that?

Comment: I have added my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `POST` request, adding `address` in the route doesn't make sense.

Edit your route to below

`Route::post('/user/profile/address/delete', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@deleteAddress',
    'as' => 'user.deleteAddress',
]);`

instead of

`Route::post('/user/profile/address/{address}/delete', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@deleteAddress',
    'as' => 'user.deleteAddress',
]);`

In your blade file, you can add a `hidden` input field which carries the `id`.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ Route('user.deleteAddress') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type='hidden' value='{{ $address->id }}' name='address_id' />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
</form>
```

In UserController, you can find an address by it's `id` and delete it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use App\Address;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function deleteAddress(Request $request) {   
    $address_id = $request->input('address_id');        
    $address = Address::find($address_id);

    if(!empty($address) && $address->user_id === Auth::user()->id){
        // for security- to make sure the delete request is valid and coming from the owner of the address.
       $address->delete();
    }

    return redirect()->back();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the `$user` and the `$address` variable, so no need to use facades:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function deleteAddress(User $user, Address $address) {   

   ... // code that checks if $user owns $address

    $address->destroy();

    return redirect()->back();
  }
}
```

Some code that 'might' be of help with checking owership:

```
$address->user->is($user); // assuming $address has a belongsTo user
```

Comment: This line "$address->user->is($user);" changed the URL, now it brings the address id. The problem. It keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: @DanielHernandez could you share the exception being thrown? and the routes file?

Comment: I shared a picture of the exception and the routes file. I updated the question. Please, look at it

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass your address id on a route then you get the value on a controller and delete address. example:

```
 <form action="{{ Route('address_delete_route')}}/{{$addess->address_id}}">


 public function deleteAddress(Request $request) {  

   //$userId = Auth::user()->userId;
   $deleteAddress = Address::find($request->userId);
   $deleteAddress->address->delete();

   return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: I changed the code of my controller. Now, in the URL I can see that it shows the address id, in the way you're meaning. The problem, it keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: Route::post('/user/profile/address/{address?}/delete'

Comment: I think this is your route declaration errors. please check your blade file and route `Route::post('/user/profile/delete/{address?}', [
    'as' => 'user_deleteAddress', 'uses' => 'UserController@deleteAddress'
]); `

Comment: Maybe is something with the Blade file. Because the route::get that I'm using for getting the address data is user/address.blade.view.
Do I have to change something?

Comment: `<div class="delete-button">
<form method="post" action="{{ route('user_deleteAddress') }}/{{$address}}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{ method_field('delete') }}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
</form>
</div>` looks this code i'm change something.

Comment: ok, perfect I think routing problem solve.can you add another problem screen short.